# PHP search function not retrieving results

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this search function all day.

```
// If breed2 NULL, search with this query
if ($breed2 == "NULL") {
    $search = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM `lstfnd` WHERE `doglf_stat` = 'Lost' AND `doglf_breed1` = '$breed1' AND `doglf_breed2` IS NULL AND `doglf_sex` = '$sex' AND `doglf_colour` = '$colour'");
// Else search with this query
} else {
    $search = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM `lstfnd` WHERE `doglf_stat` = 'Lost' AND `doglf_breed1` = '$breed1' AND `doglf_breed2` = '$breed2' AND `doglf_sex` = '$sex' AND `doglf_colour` = '$colour'");
}
$schrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);
```

The variables being used are values retrieved from dropdown lists. I've checked and:

- The variables are being inserted into the query correctly
- The query's SQL is correct and retrieves the correct records in phpMyAdmin

The problem seems to be with displaying the results.

```
while($schrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search)) {
echo ('
     <p><b><a class="blue" href="lostrep.php?lookup='.$schrow['doglf_id'].'">
    #'.$schrow['doglf_id'].' : '.$schrow['doglf_name'].'</a></b>
    <br>'.$schrow['doglf_breed1'].' X '.$schrow['doglf_breed2'].'
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    '.$schrow['doglf_sex'].
    '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    '.$schrow['doglf_age'].'
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    '.$schrow['doglf_colour'].'
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Neutered: '.$schrow['doglf_neuter'].'
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Microchipped: '.$schrow['doglf_mchip'].'
    <br>Lost in '.$schrow['doglf_pcode'].' on '.$schrow['doglf_date'].'</p>
');
}
```

I can't figure out where the issue is. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don;t check for errors of even if any rows are returned. Start there.

Comment: `$schrow = mysqli_num_rows($search);
echo($schrows);`

Nothing comes up, no error, no warning, nothing.
What quotes are you talking about?

Comment: it's pretty obvious; you've injected pure HTML into PHP.

Comment: It's in the original code, forgot to add it to the question. When I say it's not displaying, I mean there's literally nothing there. No fragments. Even the source code is blank at that portion.

Comment: It's a php page with html embedded in it. This snippet is directly below the form it's associated with.

Comment: Make a copy of your "php page", delete everything except the necessary : open database, execute selects, echo "Number of rows = " . mysqli_num_rows( $search ); . It should print on screen "Number of rows = " followed by a number, or nothing. If it's nothing, the you are getting nothing from database.

Comment: So leave only the php code for open database, execute selects, echo num rows?

Comment: Yes, let's see what it shows. By the way, RoryGilchrist's suggestion may help. Remove that unnecessary $schrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search); before the while. What is it doing there, or is it another typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many results are you expecting to return?

If there's only one, your code in the first block you posted:
`$schrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);` is getting the result, which means when you call `while ($schrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search)) {` it will be`null` and therefore nothing will be displayed. Remove `$schrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);` from the first block and give it a try.

Comment: See [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class. Every time you run `mysqli_fetch_assoc` on a result set (`$search`), it iterates to the next result.

Comment: Also,  in the first block, I'd change `breed2 == "NULL"` to `$breed2 == null`, just  stylistic thing.

Comment: The value being passed from that option in the dropdown list is a string "NULL".

Comment: Fair enough - as long as it's the string value of NULL! Hope I've helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `if (!$search) { echo mysqli_error($dbconn); }` after you did `mysqli_query` and you will see where the issue is.

Comment: this is fit as a comment really. Plus, by the look of how their code is, is obvious

Comment: Oops, I should aim beter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error in your PHP where you start printing your text.  You're missing your `print '` before your `<p>`.  Similarly, you're missing the `';` at the end of your text.

Comment: There's an echo I forgot to put in this code. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Try doing a `print_r` just inside your while loop and see if stuff is being returned.  `print "<pre>"; print_r($schrow); print "</pre>";`

Comment: Again, nothing. Complete blank.

Comment: Okay, comment out the rest of the text except for the `print_r` so that it's the only line in your while loop.  Then run it again.  Make sure you're not getting anything back by looking at the source of the page.  If you see `<pre></pre>`, then you know it's your query.  If you see other stuff in there, then you know it's the string you're echoing out.  Start by adding stuff back in a little at a time.

Comment: Nothing again. Not even `<pre></pre>`.